# How to convert opencv's face detected bounding box coordinates to dlib's face detected bounding box coordinates?

Tags: python, opencv, dlib, coordinate-transformation

I ran a live stream face detection code using opencv's pretrained dnn model & dlib's hog model.  I got detections from several cameras and the code prints out bounding box coordinates for both opencv and dlib.  I was expecting the same results but I have very different results.  Is there a way to convert the opencv coordinates to dlib's?

I've tried to find a mathematical (linear) model to connect them two but it didn't work.

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import pickle
import time
import cv2
import os
import align
import dlib
import time
import datetime

face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor_model = "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
face_aligner = align.AlignDlib(predictor_model)

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--detector", required=True,
    help="path to OpenCV's deep learning face detector")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--embedding-model", required=True,
    help="path to OpenCV's deep learning face embedding model")
ap.add_argument("-r", "--recognizer", required=True,
    help="path to model trained to recognize faces")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--le", required=True,
    help="path to label encoder")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.8,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

print("[INFO] loading face detector...")
protoPath = os.path.sep.join([args["detector"], "deploy.prototxt"])
modelPath = os.path.sep.join([args["detector"],
    "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"])
detector = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoPath, modelPath)
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(2.0)

while True:
    ret, frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    imageBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(
        cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)), 1.0, (300, 300),
        (104.0, 177.0, 123.0), swapRB=False, crop=False)
    detector.setInput(imageBlob)
    detections = detector.forward()
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
            face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            (fH, fW) = face.shape[:2]
            if fW < 20 or fH < 20:
                continue
            rgb = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            detected_faces_dlib = face_detector(rgb, 1)
            detected_faces = dlib.rectangle(left=startX, top=startY, right=endX, bottom=endY)
            print(detected_faces)
            print(detected_faces_dlib)
```

Here are the results:

```
[(333, 191) (490, 414)]
rectangles[[(-22, 47) (150, 202)]]
[(333, 190) (490, 413)]
rectangles[[(-22, 47) (150, 202)]]
[(333, 190) (491, 414)]
rectangles[[(-22, 47) (150, 202)]]
[(334, 191) (491, 416)]
rectangles[[(-22, 47) (150, 202)]]
[(334, 196) (493, 416)]
rectangles[[(-22, 47) (150, 202)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just spent a bunch of time dealing with this and if your goal is to detect facial landmarks on a face that was detected by the dnn detector, your best bet is to retrain the `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` using rectangles from the dnn detector.

Following [this article](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/training-alternative-dlib-shape-predictor-models-using-python-d1d8f8bd9f5c) as a guide, I wrote a python script that went through the ibug300 training set, re-detected the face's bounding boxes, rewrote the training set's xml file and then ran the `train_shape_predictor` script to get a new .dat file.

The results were very good compared with trying to reshape the "dnn rect" to approximate the "hog box."

One tip before you dive into retraining: The dnn face detection returns rectangles and their width and height vary a great deal. This doesn't work well for shape predictor training. It's better use a square that's sides are `~1.35 * dnn_rect.width.` Seems like a magic number, but that's the average ratio of height to width of dnn face detection rects.

Comment: So if I want to use the opencv dnn face recognition with the dlib shape predictor, without retraining, can I just turn each dnn rectangle into a square, and then pass that to the shape_predictor? Is that feasible?

Comment: Or could you share that .dat file you trained?

Comment: For anyone else who finds this question, there's [this line](https://github.com/keyurr2/facial-landmarks/blob/master/facial_landmarks.py#L88) of code I found here that modifies the dnn rectangle in a different way for supposedly better landmarking: `y1, x2 = int(y1 * 1.15), int(x2 * 1.05)`

Answer (score 0):

```
# take a bounding predicted by opencv and convert it
# to the dlib (top, right, bottom, left) 
def bb_to_rect(bb):
    top=bb[1]
    left=bb[0]
    right=bb[0]+bb[2]
    bottom=bb[1]+bb[3]
    return np.array([top, right, bottom, left]) 


# take a bounding predicted by dlib and convert it
# to the format (x, y, w, h) as we would normally do
# with OpenCV
def rect_to_bb(rect):

    x = rect.left()
    y = rect.top()
    w = rect.right() - x
    h = rect.bottom() - y

    # return a tuple of (x, y, w, h)
    return (x, y, w, h)
```